# How to extract a substring using sed on OS X?

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed

Im trying to iterate over each file and folder inside a directory and extract part of the file name into a variable, but I can't make sed work correctly. I either get all of the file name or none of it.

This version of the script should capture the entire file name:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *
do
    substring=`echo $f | sed -E -n 's/(.*)/\1/'`
    echo "sub: $substring"
done
```

But instead I get nothing:

```
sub:
sub:
sub:
sub:
...
```

This version should give me just the first character in the filename:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *
do
    substring=`echo $f | sed -E 's/^([a-zA-Z])/\1/'`
    echo "sub: $substring"
done
```

But instead I get the whole file name:

```
sub: Adlm
sub: Applications
sub: Applications (Parallels)
sub: Desktop
...
```

I've tried numerous iterations of it and what it basically boils down to is that if I use `-n` I get nothing and if I don't I get the whole file name.

Can someone show me how to get just the first character?

Or, my overall goal is to be able to extract a substring and store it into a variable, if anybody has a better approach to it, that would be appreciated as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want `grep -o` instead of sed

Comment: You should not use old and outdated backtics.  Use parentheses like this `var=$(code)`

Comment: Why did my question get down-voted? Asking so I can avoid the mistakes in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This version of the script should capture the entire file name:
>
> *sed -E -n 's/(.*)/\1/'*
>
> But instead I get nothing.

You used `-n` so naturally it won't yield anything. Perhaps you should remove `-n` or add `p`:

```
sed -E -n 's/(.*)/\1/p'
```

> This version should give me just the first character in the filename:
>
> *sed -E 's/^([a-zA-Z])/\1/'*
>
> But instead I get the whole file name,

You didn't replace anything there. Perhaps what you wanted was

```
sed -E 's/^([a-zA-Z]).*/\1/'
```

Also I suggest quoting your arguments well:

```
substring=`echo "$f" | sed ...'`
```

Finally the simpler method is to use substring expansion if you're using Bash as suggested by [kojiro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24718794/445221).

Comment: Thank you. The problem was that I was missing the .* after the capture group. This was also pointed out by others but I gave you the checkmark because you had the most complete answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to modify a shell parameter, you probably want to use a parameter expansion.

```
for f in *; do
    # This version should expand to the whole parameter
    echo "$f"
    # This version should expand to the first character in the filename
    echo "${f::1}"
done
```

Parameter expansions are not as powerful as `sed`, but they are built in to the shell (no launching a separate process or subshell necessary) and there are expansions for:

1. Substrings (as above)
2. Replacing and substituting characters
3. Altering the case of strings (bash 4+)

and more.

Comment: Thank you this is good to know. But as for my present problem, I need to know how to grab specific bits of a filename using regex. I just used the first letter of the filename in this case because it's a really simple regex and I wanted to boil the problem down to its simplest form. But next time I need substrings by index, I'll use this.

Answer (score 2):

You forget to add  `.*` after the capturing group in sed,

```
$ for i in *; do substring=`echo $i | sed -E 's/^(.).*$/\1/'`; echo "sub: $substring"; done
```

It's better to use `.` instead of `[a-zA-Z]` because it may fail if the first character starts with any special character.

Comment: You should not use old and outdated backtics.  Use parentheses like this `var=$(code)`

Comment: @Jotne yep i know. Someone said, OSX won't support `$()`

Comment: I did not find anything in Google telling that it does not work.  If you are not sure, post both and say that parentheses should be used and if it does not work, us backtics.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer awk to sed.  It seems to be easier for me to understand.

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
for f in *
do
  substring=`echo $f | awk '{print substr($1,1,1)}'`
  echo "sub: $substring"
done
```

Comment: You should not use old and outdated backtics.  Use parentheses like this `var=$(code)`